# Propagate changes in model to view in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, observablecollection, model-view

in my Silverlight 4 Application I have an ObservableCollection that I data bind to two different listboxes. The listboxitems showing the content of the MyClass-Object. When I add an item to the ObservableCollection, the new item is displayed in both listboxes properly.

I have set the Binding Mode to two way, so that editing the listboxitems will update the model automatically. This works so far. My problem is, that the **content** of the other listbox doesn't update with the updated model. Adding a new item will properly show up on the other listbox, but the updates of the content (which I checked happens) won't.

Any ideas how to achieve: The content of the other listbox should update automatically, when the I update the content in one listbox.

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on what luke said your class needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and your properties need to throw the `PropertyChanged` event in their setters.

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; // This may be named wrong

    private string _myString = null;

    public string MyString
    {
        get { return _myString; }
        set
        {
            if(value == _myString)
                return;
            _myString = value;
            var eh = PropertyChanged;
            if(eh != null)
                eh(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MyString"));
        }
    }
}
```

The `MyString` property will notify the UI that it has changed which will trigger the binding to update.

Comment: thanks for the code! One error is, that the Event call have to look like: PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));

Comment: I knew that was wrong, but I couldn't remember the exact syntax off the top of my head.  Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

you need to make sure that your objects in the observable collection implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) and they should post change events when your content properties change.